# How can I implement the video recording feature on Agora in a Vuejs project?

Tags: django, vue.js, video-recording, agora.io, videocall

I am building a project using [Vuejs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/) (frontend) and [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/overview/) (backend) in which I have integrated [Agora-Web-SDK-NG](https://agoraio-community.github.io/AgoraWebSDK-NG/docs/en/overview) for video calls.

Now, I want to add a feature of video recording and recordings will be stored in the cloud. I have researched a lot but couldn't found that [Agora-Web-SDK-NG](https://agoraio-community.github.io/AgoraWebSDK-NG/docs/en/overview) provides this feature and that too in Vuejs. I have read its [official documentation](https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_rest?platform=All%20Platforms) too but couldn't found an understanding way to implement.

**Has anyone ever been implemented this feature in Vuejs?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agora has a separate Cloud Recording SDK which works irrespective of which Video Calling SDK you're using (in this case Agora-Web-SDK-NG). Check out the documentation for the REST API [here](https://docs.agora.io/en/cloud-recording/cloud_recording_api_rest?platform=All%20Platforms).

You're just making API requests using Axios so it can be added asynchronously with your video calling application.

[This](https://medium.com/agora-io/agora-cloud-recording-quickstart-guide-with-postman-demo-c4a6b824e708) step by step guide will also help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am going to follow this, will update you soon.